# Predicting the Nan value for the age in titanic dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, vectorization

Instead of replacing the Nan age values with mean value or something similar, I got a suggestion that I should try to guess whether the person in question is a child or not and then create a is child column in the data set and add the right values for known ages and possible values for Nan.

So, I know that if in the name there is a Mr. or Mrs., it most definitely is not a child, whereas if there is a Master. or Miss., it may or may not be a child. Again I thought, if its a Master. or Miss. and the parch column( the parent child column) is non-zero, it would mean the parch count is only for parents so maybe for parch > 0 and Master. or Miss., it is a child and other cases, it is not a child.

Now my problem is, how do I code this in python? So far, I had straight forward solutions like,

```
df['isChild'] = [1 if x<=18 else 0 for x in df['Age']]
```

But this has so many conditionals and all I can think of is a for loop, iterating over each passengerId where the Age value is a Nan. Is there a simpler way? Like writing a function and just passing a data frame and it would automatically evaluate that function for every value, like a vectorized implementation ?

Here is the dataset https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data

Comment: Can you send a link to the dataset, or how to get it?

Comment: I am sorry, I just added the link

Comment: did you see this kaggle ? https://www.kaggle.com/yassineghouzam/titanic-top-4-with-ensemble-modeling, the way he using impute the miss age, convince myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `apply` method of pandas:

```
def conditions(row):
     if row.Age <= 18:
         return 1
     elif condition:
         ...

df['isChild'] = df.apply(conditions, axis=1)
```

Comment: But my problem is, isChild is now not only dependent on age but also on parch column and Name column. If age is Nan, then isChild will totally depend on parch and Name. How does apply solve this problem, because all I can see here is a dependency on one column for a new column

Comment: @Krash You can still use apply. I just updated my answer.